# Kubernetes nginx ingress: How to redirect foo.example.org to example.org?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

My ingress currently looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.org
        - app.example.org
      secretName: prod-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.org
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: app-service
              servicePort: 80
    - host: app.example.org
        http:
          paths:
              - path: /
                backend:
                  serviceName: app-service
                  servicePort: 80
```

But now I want to redirect `app.example.org` to `example.org` instead. How can I do this?

I found [this example](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/605#issuecomment-297022809) using `ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` but I don't know what domains that will apply to?

I'm using Helm `nginx-ingress-1.37.0`; app ver 0.32.0.

Answer (score 15):

For Kubernetes 1.19 and up, this ingress will redirect all traffic from app.example.org to example.org:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      return 301 $scheme://example.org$request_uri;
  name: ingress-redirect
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app.example.org
    secretName: prod-tls
  rules:
  - host: app.example.org
```

Answer (score 7):

Ingress controller version 0.22.0 or higher uses `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` instead of `ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet`. So this would be the new for the @mdaniel answer:

```yaml
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ingress
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    spec:
      tls:
        - hosts:
            - example.org
          secretName: prod-tls
      rules:
        - host: example.org
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /
                backend:
                  serviceName: app-service
                  servicePort: 80
    ---
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ingress-redirect
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "https://example.org/$1"
    spec:
      tls:
        - hosts:
            - app.example.org
          secretName: prod-tls
      rules:
        - host: app.example.org
          http:
              paths:
                  - path: /
                    backend:
                      serviceName: app-service
                      servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: https://example.org` to keep 301 permanent redirect https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#permanent-redirect

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Is this really correct? rewrite-target is for altering the uri passed upstream, not to send location header to client?

Answer (score 5):

> I found this example using `ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet:` but I don't know what domains that will apply to?

It's easier to reason about that configuration when you have two Ingresses, one just for "hosting" the `configuration-snippet:` and the other for doing the real work:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.org
      secretName: prod-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.org
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: app-service
              servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-redirect
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # this should be covered by the annotation on the other ingress
    # since it will renew the same certificate
    # cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 permanent;
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - app.example.org
      secretName: prod-tls
  rules:
    - host: app.example.org
      http:
          paths:
              - path: /
                backend:
                  serviceName: app-service
                  servicePort: 80
```